# What does Advanceable Added in API level 16 mean?

Tags: android, launcher

What does Advanceable Added in API level 16 mean? And how to use those two methods in Advanceable Api?I saw this interface in Launcher source code. I am not clear about the specification in android docs.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that only devices with api level 16 or above knows/can use that method/class. And will fail to run if you put the code  under a device with api level 15 or lower.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and my poor English.But What I want to know is what doesthe "Advanceable" API means.Here is the link to this Interface doc http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/Advanceable.html